# How does Qt mobile work?

Tags: qt, mobile, architecture

in Qt 5.4 it is possible to develop Apps for Android and iOS. I want to understand the architecture behind it. There is nothing regarding this in the docu of Qt.

Comment: This is too broad a question. (and apparently incomplete?) Platform-specific implementation in Qt is done in the Qt Platform Plugins: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpa.html

Comment: You're not developing a native app with Qt mobile. There have to be some mechanisms on how to get the app work on the platform. Consider for example Xamarin, where you develop an app in C#. Xamarin uses the Mono Framework and depending on which it platform you're targeting it works a little bit different. Rughly speaking you can say for iOS it uses bindings to access the Objective-C world and for Android it uses JNI. You may have a look at their docu: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/. This is what I'm expectiing form Qt as well.

Comment: There are YouTube tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suPeZ7XC1xk. Happy coding :)

Comment: Absolutely valid question. I want to know how it works. Does it compile code to "Native" like Xamarin or does something else ?? Why is this question downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to Android, you might start here.

Bogdan Vatra is the guy behind the Android Qt implementation:

http://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-1/

Comment: Not to my knowledge, I'm afraid.